# Do real quadratic fields with unique primary factorization exist?

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

Bumped in Stillwell's book "Elements of Number Theory" into "The real quadratic fields with unique prime factorization are still not known ...". But doesn't $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$'s ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ have that property?

Comment: Yes, it has unique factorization.

Comment: I suspect that what was written was that nobody knows if there are infinitely many real quadratic fields with this property.  As you say, there are certainly known examples.

Comment: Here's a literal quote from the book: "The real quadratic fields with unique prime factorization are still not known, nor is it known whether there are infinitely many of them".

Comment: Would it help if we wrote "Not all ____ are known. In particular we do not know whether there are infinitely many" Let me add that many examples are known, and it seems likely that there are infinitely many.

Comment: I can now see how "are still not known" when put in the context can mean "not understood as well as imaginary quadratic fields". But as someone who's just getting familiarized oneself with these concepts, the wording could have been better. Anyway, thanks everyone for clarification.

Answer (score 5):

see   https://oeis.org/A003172   and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_number_fields_with_class_number_one#Real_quadratic_fields
for some detail.

The difference, quite enormous, from imaginary quadratic fields is that those have only a handful of class number one, and it was a huge endeavor to prove the known list complete. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark%E2%80%93Heegner_theorem

For real, everyone expects that there are infinitely many. However, in a few cases, notably $$ 229,\; 257, \; 401, $$ despite being primes congruent to $1 \pmod 4,$ the class number is larger than one (although still odd). If the thing gave class number one for all such primes, we would be able to say that we knew there were infinitely many, but it does not **always** work.

Comment: Your final reference gives me a 404 error,  pls fix.  Thank you.

Comment: @OscarLanzi they discontinued the blog and did not give any alternate place for the posts.

Comment: Can you or I delete the lost reference then?

Comment: Yes, go ahead...

Comment: Alas, the sad story plays out.  The moral that you likely know:  always give  important summaries with your references so that at least some information survives.

Comment: @OscarLanzi  I do have my own Latex original as a pdf, I can email that to you.